# About condition of an important convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I remember there is a property that if a sequence of functions converges in $L^{p}$, then there is a subsequence such that they converge to f pointwise almost everywhere. But I kind of forget the specific condition for p, I guess p should be any real number greater or equals 1. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: It's also true if $p=\infty$ for that matter.